# underscore - filtering two dimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array, filter, underscore.js

I am trying to filter two-dimensional array like var arr = [ [object, object], [object, object], [object, object] ] and return the same structure.
Any ideas?

Comment: Filter by what? Filter in which dimension?

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `filter` and `map` will do it:

```
_.map(arr, function(subarr) {
    return _.filter(subarr, itemcondition)
})
// or:
_.map(arr, _.partial(_.filter, _, itemcondition));
```